# WebClient DownloadFile Illegal characters in path

Tags: c#, image, csv

I'm a newbie, so I'm sure this is something really basic that I'm missing.

I have a simple program to run through a `csv` file that contains links to images to save those images in the specified save file location.

I am parsing the cell that contains the `url` into a `List<string[]>`.

If I put `GetImage(@"http://www.example.com/picture.jpg", 1)` my `GetImage` function performs as it should.  When I try to use the loop and pass in the `str[0]` variable, I receive an error about illegal characters in path.

I've used a `MessageBox` to tell me what the difference is and as far as I can tell, when I pass the `str[0]` into the function it adds double quotes(i.e., "http://www.example.com" is displayed instead of http://www.example.com as it is when I just send the one string.

What am I doing wrong?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = textBox1.Text;            
        folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        string saveLocation = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        textBox2.Text = saveLocation;            
        List<string[]> file = parseCSV(fileName);
        int count = 0;
        foreach (string[] str in file)
        {
            if (count != 0)
            {                                                          
                GetImage(str[0], str[4]);                    
            }
            count++;
        }
        //GetImage(@"http://www.example.com/picture.jpg", "1");
    }


    private void GetImage(string url, string prodID)
    {   
        string saveLocation = textBox2.Text + @"\";;
        saveLocation += prodID + ".jpg";                        
        WebClient webClt = new WebClient();
        webClt.DownloadFile(url, saveLocation);                         
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible that your CSV file contains the double quotes? Then you should Replace these...

Comment: My csv file does not have them...

Comment: Maybe the problem is with `saveLocation` ? it's better to use `Path.Combine()` for paths (way better than `textBox2.Text + @"\" + prodID + ".jpg";`). Can you check what's the value of saveLocation ?

Comment: If I comment out out the foreach loop and uncomment the GetImage(@"http://www.example.com/picture.jpg", "1"), it saves the file correctly, so I don't think it's the saveLocation.  Although I will look into changing in the way I'm saving it.

Comment: Try calling `webClt.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), saveLocation);`, it seems some of the input is not valid uris.

Comment: @user1744966 can you post an example of the content of `List<string[]> file`?

Comment: @Ingenu, I think you're on the right track.  Now I get an error about the URI scheme not being valid.  I'm pretty sure it's probably b/c of the quotes (but that's just a guess), but I don't know where the quotes are coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter which function or method creates these quotes, you could replace them all.

```
String myUrl = str[0];
myUrl = myUrl.Replace("\"", "");
GetImage(myUrl, str[4]);
```

I think your files contains the quotes or the parseCSV method creates them.

Update:

I used this code and it works with no problem at all and without quotes:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string fileName = "Test";
  //folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
  string saveLocation = ".\\";
  //textBox2.Text = saveLocation;
  List<string[]> file = new List<string[]>
  {
    new string[] { "http://www.example.com", "1", "1", "1", "1"},
    new string[] { "http://www.example.com", "2", "2", "2", "2"},
  };
  int count = 0;
  foreach (string[] str in file)
  {
    if (count != 0)
    {
        GetImage(str[0], str[4]);
    }
    count++;
  }
//GetImage(@"http://www.example.com/picture.jpg", "1");
}


private static void GetImage(string url, string prodID)
{
  string saveLocation = ".\\"; // textBox2.Text + @"\"; ;
  saveLocation += prodID + ".jpg";
  WebClient webClt = new WebClient();
  Console.WriteLine(url);
  webClt.DownloadFile(url, saveLocation);
}
```

Comment: Tried that, no difference.  My csv file does not have the quotes (unless they are somehow hidden).  And I'm pretty certain they aren't being put in on the parseCSV. 
    `using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(pth))
             {
                   string line;
                   string[] row;

                   while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                   {
                       row = line.Split(',');
                       parsedData.Add(row);                       
                   }
               }`

Comment: It works because you explicitly defined the string[].  My problem is when it's getting the string from the parseCSV.  I tried to post that code in the previous comment, but it came out a little ugly.  I just don't know where the quotes are coming from and why string replace doesn't remove them.

Comment: Well, for some reason when I tried to replace it before sending as you originally suggested, it didn't work.  But I this: `GetImage(str[0].Replace("\"", ""), str[4]);` has fixed the issue.  Thanks for the help.